# What benefits come from using value converters in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What benefits come from using value converters in XAML? Why not have view-models provide correct values to views in the first place without any need to convert?

Comment: You may provide a case not benefits from it in your use case, or this question is too broad.

Comment: So you gonna copy/past the same converter function in every viewmodel you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many things you are correct and it isn't somehow "wrong" for a viewmodel to do translation. It's often more convenient to do so in a viewmodel or whilst copying data from a model into a viewmodel.

A viewmodel can use an injected class which provides re-usable behaviour. Hence simple re-usability isn't unique to converters.

It's not a "given" that a converter is always the thing to choose.

A converter lives in the View layer and hence in a project which will already have references to view visuals, controls, enumeration. When you want to return Visibility.Hidden then that enumeration is in System.Windows. If your viewmodel is in a class library then it won't have a reference to that dll at all. Similarly with brushes, colours etc.
Maybe you don't have big solutions so your viewmodels are always in the same exe as your views and hence that reference doesn't matter.

Not much of an advantage there then.

If you have a converter as an application resource there will only be one instance of it. ( Unless you do something like set x:Shared false.)

Assuming you merge the resource dictionary which creates the instance in app.xaml. This is often neither here nor there from a memory perspective but you can fine tune it so you have an instance per usage or per scope ( like say a window ) or application.

A viewmodel can have an object which is a static or instance class.  There is a very niche use case where the difference could be significant.

Maybe you "really" just want to convert a property off something which isn't a viewmodel. You could bind it to a property or just go direct with a converter. Again, not a huge advantage there.

You can make a converter (also) a custom markup extension:

http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/03/17/tips-and-tricks-making-value-converters-more-accessible-in-markup/

```
public class DummyConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private static DummyConverter _converter = null;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_converter == null)
        {
            _converter = new DummyConverter();
        }
        return _converter;
    }
```

The above will give you one single instance of underlying behaviour like a converter as a resource would do. 
Alternatively, you can instead just return "this" and have an instance per usage. Since this is a markup extension you can add properties set in xaml to pass fixed parameters.

This means you can encapsulate behaviour resulting from several properties into one piece of code.

Imagine an instance where you need a reference to something in the view. Maybe this is the window. But your binding is in some usercontrol. You can use a multibinding and a multiconverter to go get a reference to the window's width, height, background... whatever you like. The converter can then translate any number of properties off view elements and do whatever you need with that. All in the view. The viewmodel doesn't need to know about what a window is for this to work.

Which is elegant and suchlike.

Perhaps more significantly, you can still exercise unit tests on your viewmodel as a discrete instance if it doesn't need a view instantiated to work.

Readability and flexibility are potential plusses.

Say you want several values based on one property. You could add a property per variation to your viewmodel. That will get quite clunky quite quickly though and you're changing code in a viewmodel as well as using that in a view.

I'll give you a concrete example here.

In the wargame I'm working on there are units. Each contains one or more nato symbols which are rectangular with various crosses, ellipses etc in them. The size of a unit is something a scenario designer can control. Hence the size is bound. The width and height of each symbol is a proportion of unit size.  When  you have 2 such symbols ( the number shows strength 1-4) the width and height is a proportion and the gap between another.
If you were to look at the markup for each you would see numerous instances of a multiplier converter. Each has a multiplier parameter. This might be 0.35, 0.02, 0.16 times the piece size. Size has a fallback value so you can see a unit in  the designer. Whilst building this I could easily change each multiplier to check what things looked like. It would have been much less convenient doing this in the viewmodel.

Comment: Are you really saying, that the two big advantages of a standalone converter implementation over a conversion inside the view model are, that the converter instance is reused in the scope of the parent `ResourceDictionary` (when declared inside a `ResourceDictionary` and the `x:Shared` attribute set to `true`)? And that you can create a class that extends `MarkupExtension` and implements `IValueConverter`? Also _"Converters also have a bindable converterparameter property."_ is not true. `ConverterParameter` is a property of `Binding` and it is not bindable as it is not a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: No I'm not. A regular converter doesn't need that attribute set at all to be a singleton.  I  thought I removed that part about binding the parameter. Fixed thanks.

Comment: No, this attribute is implicitly set to `true` by default. I just wanted to make clear that this is not the rule, but rather depends on the declaration of the converter. Singleton is a design pattern that ensures that a static instance can only exist once in the static scope. The XAML parser doesn't follow this pattern. The instance created is not static and it is not a single instance. The parser reuses a single instance in the _current scope_ (when `x:Shared="True"`). As there can be multiple scopes, so can there be multiple instances of the resource object. No offense, I am just saying.

Comment: Umm... I thought I covered the aspect of scope clearly enough. Maybe not.

Comment: You were misusing the term Singleton in this context.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that value converter can be reused

You have many controls in the xaml need the same convert logic, and the controls have their own viewmodel, you will have to write the same code over and over again

Answer (score 1):

There are many scenarios.

Converters can change data from one type to another, translate data based on cultural information, or modify other aspects of the presentation.

Here is what you can read about it on Microsoft Docs: [Data conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframework-4.8#data-conversion)

> The following are some typical scenarios where it makes sense to implement a data converter:
>
> - Your data should be displayed differently, depending on culture. For
>     instance, you might want to implement a currency converter or a
>     calendar date/time converter based on the conventions used in a
>     particular culture.
> - The data being used is not necessarily intended to change the text
>     value of a property, but is instead intended to change some other
>     value, such as the source for an image, or the color or style of the
>     display text. Converters can be used in this instance by converting
>     the binding of a property that might not seem to be appropriate, such
>     as binding a text field to the Background property of a table cell.
> - More than one control or multiple properties of controls are bound to
>     the same data. In this case, the primary binding might just display
>     the text, whereas other bindings handle specific display issues but
>     still use the same binding as source information.
> - A target property has a collection of bindings, which is termed
>     MultiBinding. For MultiBinding, you use a custom IMultiValueConverter
>     to produce a final value from the values of the bindings. For
>     example, color may be computed from red, blue, and green values,
>     which can be values from the same or different binding source
>     objects. See MultiBinding for examples and information.

Your question:
*"Why not have viewmodels provide correct values to views in the first place without any need to convert?"*

View model should not deal with presentation details like UI logic or appearance. Otherwise the separation or loose coupling between view and view model is no more given. The view model just presents the required data for a specific context (or user stories). It doesn't know about view related design constraints like coloring or visual states. For example, if you want to represent data as a visual state of a control, you have to convert the data value e.g. to a color or `Visibility`. Value converters help to maintain the loose coupling between view and view model.